# Project Euler program 1 code barely not getting the correct answer

Tags: java

```
int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;
    int w = 0;
    int v = 0;

    while ((x + 3) < 1000)
        {
            x = (x + 3);

            if ((x % 15) != 0)
            {
                w = (w + x);
            }
        }

    while ((y + 5) < 1000)
        {
            y = (y + 5);
            z = (z + y);
        }

    v = (w + z);

    System.out.println("w = " + w);
    System.out.println("z = " + z);
    System.out.println("v = " + v);
```

I know it's really sloppy, but I can't figure out why the output is incorrect (off by around 100-200). Any ideas?

EDIT: Ok so it was wrong by around 33 thousand. Anyway, here's my revised code.

Comment: Here's the question for anyone that's wondering: http://projecteuler.net/problem=1, though I'm having a hard time figuring out what you are trying to do and the variable names don't make it any easier.

Comment: Consider what is happening for e.g. 15.

Comment: "What would Gauss do?"  They really should give you extra points for solving this without a loop.

Comment: ajb: Can you clarify please?

Keikoku: The variable names aren't supposed to make sense, I just kind of threw this together as fast as I could which is probably why it didn't work at first.

Comment: @user2770254 You can get the answer just by using formulas for summing arithmetic sequences.  `(3 * ((999 / 3) * ((999 / 3) + 1) / 2)) + (5 * ((999 / 5) * ((999 / 5) + 1) / 2)) - (15 * ((999 / 15) * ((999 / 15) + 1) / 2))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're off by 33 thousand.

Your problem is that you count the numbers that are divisible by both 3 and 5 twice.

You need to either redesign your loop so that you evade those numbers, or check in the second loop whether the number isn't divisible by 3. If it is, you don't add it up.

Comment: I revealed the mystery too soon, didn't I?

Comment: Hmm. Yeah, definitely off by 33 thousand. Oops.

Also, the problem states that it has to be divisible by 3 OR 5. So can't I keep numbers in the second loop that aren't divisible by 3?

As an aside, I checked this program for less than 10 and less than 15 and the answers were correct. Why would increasing the range to 1000 make it incorrect?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what means to "keep" the numbers, but yeah, try it and you'll see :). Try to increase the range to 16. The minimal number that is divisible by both 3 and 5 is 15. And it will be counted twice instead of just once.

Comment: Ohhhhhh. That makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Comment: I love that "Ohhhhhh." moment. Happens every time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the `%` (modulus) operator?  It's great for Euler problems.

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 3; i < 1000; i++)
{
    if(i%3 == 0 || i%5 == 0)
    {
        sum = sum + i;
    }
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

But to see your problem:

```
int total = 0;
int threes = 0;
int fives = 0;
int total = 0;
int mutually_exclusive = 0;

//collect all divisible by 3
while (threes < 1000)
{
    //find mutually exclusive
    if(threes % 5 == 0)
    {
        mutually_exclusive = mutually_exclusive + threes;
    }
    total = total + threes;
    threes = threes + 3;
}

while (fives < 1000)
{
    total = total + fives ;
    fives = fives + 5;
}

//delete mutually exclusive to avoid duplicates
total = total - mutually_exclusive;
System.out.println("total = " + total);
```

Comment: I just started learning programming so I'm basically just learning as I go. This is pretty out of my comfort zone but I'm trying to learn. Thanks, I'm familiar with the % operator and I'll agree that it's probably the best solution.